# WCF Service Reference inheriting from another WCF Service

Tags: wcf, architecture

I have a WCF Project named EmployeeGateway this WCF Project has been added as a WCF service reference to another WCF Project named CompanyService

EmployeeGateway has an Object named EmployeeView

In CompanyService I have an object with the same name 'EmployeeView' which inherits from EmployeeGateway.EmployeeView

[DataContract]
public class EmployeeView : EmployeeGateway::EmployeeView { additionalfields }

Now, I have a third project named CompanyUI (MVC) which has a service reference to CompanyService.

The problem is that the generated code in the reference.cs file has a:

public partial class EmployeeView :

and a

public partial class EmployeeView**1** : {Namespace}.EmployeeView { fields }

Is it possible for this file to be generated without the 1 at the end of the name?  Can it somehow be fully qualified?  For example: The reference file contains {Namespace}.EmployeeGateway.EmployeeView and {Namespace}.CompanyService.EmployeeView (which would inherit from the EmployeeGateway?

If not, I wonder if it possible to not even expose the EmployeeGateway.Employee view at all within the CompanyUI project?

Really though, I don't like that the method that i'm calling has the number 1 at the end of it and am looking for options on how to properly fix it.

Thanks for any assistance.
Steven.